# How do you sign a Java Midlet?

Tags: java, midlet, sign

A simple question with a fairly complicated answer:

How do you sign a Java Midlet so you can load it onto a mobile phone with less security prompts?

Comment: +1: I was looking for something like this (+: N00b to J2ME

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Get required software**

1. [Java SDK (JDK)](http://javashoplm.sun.com/ECom/docs/Welcome.jsp?StoreId=22&PartDetailId=j2sdk-1.4.2_08-oth-JPR&SiteId=JSC&TransactionId=noreg) from [Sun](http://www.sun.com/java/) (you should already have this)
2. [Java Wireless Toolkit (WTK)](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download-2_2.html) also from [Sun](http://www.sun.com/java/)
3. Optionally get and install [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) to allow you to automate your build (I'd strongly recommend these)

**Import an existing certificate (if you have one)**

1. If you've purchased a certificate from Verisign (or another provider) you need to import the certificate into your J2SE keystore.
2. Try using the following command `keytool -import -alias {myalias} -file {mycertificate}` (I haven't been able to test this since I don't have a proper certificate)
3. Run `keytool -list` to see your new certificate
4. Next you must export the certificate so you can import it to your phone
5. Run `keytool -export -alias {myalias} -file mycertificate.crt`
6. Import the certificate into your phone (see below for details)

**Create and import a new (test) certificate**

1. You need to use [keytool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) (from the JDK)
2. I used the following command `keytool -genkey -alias {myalias} -keyalg RSA -validity 365`
3. This will prompt you for a keystore password, enter your keystore password (if you have an existing keystore) or the one you want to use if you don't have one yet
4. Fill in all the prompts about location/company name etc.
5. Run `keytool -list` to see your new certificate
6. Next you must export the certificate so you can import it to your phone
7. Run `keytool -export -alias {myalias} -file mycertificate.crt`
8. Import the certificate into your phone (see below for details)

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.2_08\bin&gt;keytool -genkey -alias company -keyalg RSA -validity 365
Enter keystore password: password
What is your first and last name? [Unknown]: My Name
What is the name of your organizational unit? [Unknown]: company
What is the name of your organization? [Unknown]: company
What is the name of your City or Locality? [Unknown]: location
What is the name of your State or Province? [Unknown]: location2
What is the two-letter country code for this unit? [Unknown]: GB
Is CN=My Name, OU=company, O=company, L=location, ST=location2, C=GB correct? [no]: yes
Enter key password for (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

**Build and package the application**

1. Use [`javac`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) to build your MIDlet paying special attention to your classpath and bootclasspath options (otherwise preverification will fail). I also set target to 1.1 and source to 1.3
2. Generate your JAD file the critical attributes in the JAD are
    MIDlet-Jar-URL, MIDlet-Jar-Size, MIDlet-Permissions we also included MIDlet-Icon, MicroEdition-Configuration, MicroEdition-Profile, MIDlet-Name, MIDlet-Push-1, MIDlet-Icon, MIDlet-Description and MIDlet-Version
3. Generate the MANIFEST.MF file based on your JAD, you must remove MIDlet-Jar-Size and `MIDlet-Jar-URL`
4. Both these tasks can be completed using the wtkJad Antenna task
5. Package and preverify the app using the wtkPackage Antenna Task you must set the classpath and bootclasspath properties correctly otherwise Preverification will fail

**Sign the application**

1. Sign the Application using [`jarsigner`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jarsigner.html)
2. Run `jarsigner -keystore {mykeystore} -storepass (mypassword} {myjar} {myalias}`
3. Now you have a signed jar you need to update the `MIDlet-Jar-Size` in your JAD
4. Now add the certificate to the JAD using [`JadTool.jar`](http://java.sun.com/j2me/docs/wtk2.2/docs/UserGuide-html/commandline.html) from the WTK
5. Run `java -jar JadTool.jar -addcert -alias {myalias} -storepass {mypassword} -keystore {mykeystore} -inputjad {myinputjad} -outputjad {myoutputjad}`
6. Now add the signature to the JAD again using [`JadTool.jar`](http://java.sun.com/j2me/docs/wtk2.2/docs/UserGuide-html/commandline.html)
7. Run `java -jar JadTool.jar -addjarsig -alias {myalias} -jarfile {myjar} -storepass {mypassword} -keypass {mypassword} -keystore {mykeystore} -inputjad {myinputjad} -outputjad {myoutputjad}`

**Deployment**

1. Deploy this to a web server with the MIME types set correctly and download it to your phone and it will be a trusted 3rd party application
2. You can also deploy applications to phones by sending the JAR & JAD to the phone over Bluetooth or Infrared or a cable depending on your phones features. On Nokia phones the files
   appear in your SMS Inbox

**Installing the Certificate on the phone**

1. Import the certificate into your phone, in Windows XP SP2 I could do
   this by right clicking the file and selecting "Send to Bluetooth Device",
   you should be able to send files by cable or Infra Red (IR) too. NB: I
   haven't found anyway of importing a certificate on a Series 40 phone
2. Once the certificate is installed it needs to be authorised for
   "Application Installation". On my phone (Nokia 6680) this is under
   Tools->Settings->Certificate Management->Trust Settings, I turned on
   everything but I think "Application Installation" is all you need

**Common Problems**

1. Application not installed using the JAD: The application is only trusted if it is installed using the JAD, the application will still install from the jar but it won't be trusted.
2. Application trust settings not set: Once your application is installed you need to specify how much trust to give it (it doesn't get all permissions by default). On a Nokia Series 60 phone these are found under the App. Manager.
3. Root certificate missing from phone: The Java Verified certificate and/or Verisign certificates are missing from some phones check under Tools->Settings->Certificate Management for the relevant certificate
4. Authorization Failed: - There are a whole host of possible reasons behind this here are the ones I've come across

   1. Certificate missing from phone, double check your certificate is installed and has been marked as trusted for application installs in Certificate Management
   2. Reboot: Uninstall the application completely then reboot your phone try taking the battery and SIM out too, often things get themselves in a twist, especially if you've been re-installing a lot without uninstalling first
   3. JAD/JAR mismatch: Double check the application size in the JAD, remember it's the number of bytes that is important NOT the size on disk
   4. Browser cache: If you're installing over the air make sure you clear your browser cache before installing
   5. I've heard but not verified that line breaks in the `MIDlet-Permissions` can cause problems but it seems ok to me on Nokia 6680/6630/6230i (could be firmware dependent?)
   6. The `MIDlet-Permissions` attribute is the cause of a lot of problems (especially since the documentation is often wrong/missing or different depending on the phone), try leaving it out first and add permissions in one at a time. Some phones will complain about permissions they don't support, some will ignore them
5. There is a bug in some early Nokia 6600 firmwares that stop the install of trusted MIDlets
6. Certificate not valid yet: If you generated the certificate yourself it may have a start validity date of tomorrow, also if your PC and phone dates are different you may be outside the period of validity of the certificate
7. No certificate management on Series 40 phones, you can install a signed application but behavior is strange with self signed certificates
8. JadTool problems: I haven't experienced any of these issues but lots of other people have

   1. "I have issues if I try to use the jadtool manually. I have a certificate chain and can't seem to get the second certificate added to the JAD file using any WTK jadtool. The interesting part however is that I can successfully sign the midlet using any of the same WTK GUI interfaces - they add the second certificate correctly. My steps:

      1. Use 1.4.2_06 jarsigner.exe to sign jar
      2. Use WTK (2.2 or 2.3 beta) jadtool to addcert with certnum 1
      3. If I call jadtool to addcert with certnum 2 the same certificate is inserted as cert 1-2 I'm assuming I am doing something incorrectly since the WTK gui seems to be working just fine"
   2. "I received a post on the KVM news group on the topic that states there is a bug in the jadtool and the author claims to have filed a bug report and posted a patch: http://archives.java.sun.com/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0508&L=kvm-interest&F=&S=&P=9858 One interesting note that was also posted was that the cert JAD params are static so once you get them from the WTK correctly you can put them statically in the ant script."
   3. "I am trying to sign a MIdlet for Nokia 6620 device. I am using a Verisign Code Signing certificate that actually contains two certificates (User and Intermediate CA). I am using the WTK 2.2 signing tool. Do you know if this tool support two certificates when signing ? The signature is added to the JAD file with two certificates but I have been getting security error when installing. I have checked on the device and there are different root certificates installed for Verisign but it still fails !
   4. "If you want, you can download the sprintpcs developer kit as it supports dual certs (http://developer.sprintpcs.com). However, I never got that cert to work on the Nokia (6620/cingular) phone, although it does work on sprint phones (with developer root enabled). Ultimately, I only got things to work by creating the cert as described in this blog and installing that on the phone. Bizarrely, even though the root cert for my versign-signed cert *was* on the 6620 phone, it still would never install my MIDlet as you would think it should."
9. Old phones (6230/i, 6682) don't support x509 certificates, WPKI has been suggested as a possible solution but I haven't investigated this
10. Socket connections can be problematic ([http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68306](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68306%20) ) possibly due to the WAP infrastructure and the services provided by an operator. HTTP is a much safer protocol to use
11. "Go online and check application validity": Yes/No. If I click on yes button the phone I get the following error: "Certificate revoked for this application" and the installation fails. To rectify this go to Tools -> Manager -> Menu -> Settings -> Online Certif Check [ On / Off / Required] There is also a Default address setting. If the online control setting is required, the check will fail, if there is no default address. see http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71071

**Trust Domains**

1. There are 4 different trust domains in MIDP2 (manufacturer, operator, trusted third party, and untrusted). Trusted Third Party is the only one of any use to us really.It gives the following options on my Nokia 6680 (Vodafone UK):
  Network Access: Not Allowed, Ask every time, Ask first time
      Messaging: Not Allowed, Ask every time App
      Auto-Start: Not Allowed, Ask every time, Ask first time
      Connectivity: Not Allowed, Ask every time, Ask first time, Always allowed
      Multimedia: Not Allowed, Ask every time, Ask first time
      Read User Data: Not Allowed, Ask every time, Ask first time, Always allowed
      Edit User Data: Not Allowed, Ask every time, Ask first time, Always allowed
2. These settings are defined by the operator and the phone manufacturer and therefore vary between phone, manufacturer and operator.

**Unresolved Problems**

1. I managed to sign the JAD with this format using J2ME WTK utilities, but when trying to install it on the device I get a message "Application authentication failed 909".

**Sample JAD**

```
MIDlet-Jar-URL: MyApp.jar
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 201365
MIDlet-Name: MyApp
MIDlet-Vendor: EC1M
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MIDlet-Icon: logo.png
MIDlet-Push-1: sms://:6553,net.ec1m.MyApp.midp.MyAppMIDlet,*
MIDlet-Description: MyApp MIDlet
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry,javax.microedition.io.Connector.sms...
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.67 MIDlet-1: MyApp, logo.png,net.ec1m.MyApp.midp.MyAppMIDlet
MIDlet-Certificate-1-1: MIICODCCAaECBEKqpfswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQAwYz...=
MIDlet-Jar-RSA-SHA1: EUsAch/.../hEZOsJsiCjBOhNs/3FSw4=
```

**Sample Manifest**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
MIDlet-Name: MyApp  
Created-By: 1.4.2_05-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
MIDlet-Push-1: sms://:6553,net.ec1m.MyApp.midp.MyAppMIDlet,*
MIDlet-1: MyApp, logo.png, net.ec1m.MyApp.midp.MyAppMIDlet
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.2
MIDlet-Icon: logo.png
MIDlet-Vendor: EC1M
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition...
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.67
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MIDlet-Description: MyApp MIDlet
```

**Sample Ant Build File**
I've put our [EC1M](http://www.ec1m.net) [ant build file](http://www.ec1m.net/downloads.htm) up on our website to (hopefully) make all this a little easier for you.
**Other Resources**
This [FAQ on the Nokia Forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=85660) is worth a read.

Comment: i have installed its root certificate certificate..

using this 
symcaimport.redelijkheid.com/

now 
settings>security>certificates>godaddy>select use>

there are three options

server auth.
cross certi.
app signing


among which app sign is disabled.. 


and when i install the app and click on it it shows invalid application "Delete ?" 


rot certificate i have installed is from 
https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.seam
Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority Root Certificate (DER Format)

but is shows "Certificate not found on Phone or SIM"

Comment: I installed the certificate on my mobile phone (`Nokia Asha 302`) but when I go to `Certificate Management` the `Applications Signing` option is greyed out so I get the error `Certificate not on device or SIM` when I try to open it. How can I enable it? I'm desperate! I'm trying to sign a self-made application for 2 days and I can't get it working! :(

Comment: Most of the links like sun.java.x@#$%  etc are dead links. Could you please update them . Your post is very helpful on the other hand.

Comment: Hi, I'm not likely to find time to hunt down all the dead links and replace them with current ones. If you've found the current ones feel free to edit my post though

Answer (score 2):

Step1:
    Create CSR request which may be raised by

```
1) Creating keystore and using that generate CSR file.
2) Perform steps given by certificate authority and download CSR and private key files.
```

Step2:
    Give your information to certificate authority for verification.

Step3:
    You will be provided a certificate for code signing.

Step4:
    You need to down load intermediate certificate along with root certificate.

Step5:
    Now you will be having your_domain_name.crt, IntCertCA.crt, TrustedRoot.crt

```
Now you need to create a chained certificate by combining all above certificates.

1) Open a text editor (such as wordpad) and paste the entire body of each certificate into one text file in the following order:

    The Primary Certificate - your_domain_name.crt
    The Intermediate Certificate - IntCertCA.crt
    The Root Certificate - TrustedRoot.crt
    Make sure to include the beginning and end tags on each certificate. The result should look like this:

    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
    (Your Primary SSL certificate: your_domain_name.crt) 
    -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
    (Your Intermediate certificate: IntCertCA.crt) 
    -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
    (Your Root certificate: TrustedRoot.crt) 
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----

    Save the combined file as your_domain_name.pem. The .pem file is now ready to use.
```

Step6:
        Import private key into your your_domain_name.pem

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in your_domain_name.pem -inkey your_private_key.key -out output_file_name.p12 -name your_alias


    NOTE: PLEASE REMOVE \ FROM FOLLOWING COMMANDS AND EXECUTE ( \ IS BASICALLY COMMAND CONTINUETY )
```

Step7:
        Create keystore from output_file_name.p12

```
    keytool -importkeystore \
     -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore your_domain_keystore.ks \
     -srckeystore output_file_name.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass your_store_password \
     -alias your_alias
```

Step8: 
        NOTE: PLEASE TAKE BACKUP OF YOUR JAD FILE BEFORE TRIGGERING FOLLOWING COMMANDS.

```
    Add your certificates to your your_midlet_name.jad file.

    java -jar JadTool.jar -addcert -alias your_alias \
    -storepass your_store_password \
    -keystore your_domain_keystore.ks \
    -inputjad your_midlet_name.jad -outputjad your_midlet_name.jad
```

Step9:
        NOTE: PLEASE TAKE BACKUP OF YOUR JAD FILE BEFORE TRIGGERING FOLLOWING COMMANDS.

```
    Sign your midlet, also use your_midlet_name.jad file generated from Step8.

    java -jar JadTool.jar -addjarsig \
    -alias your_store_password \
    -storepass your_store_password \
    -keypass your_store_password \
    -keystore your_domain_keystore.ks \
    -inputjad your_midlet_name.jad -outputjad your_midlet_name.jad
```