# How do I sign a Java midlet?

Tags: java, java-me, certificate, midlet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you sign a Java Midlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383771/how-do-you-sign-a-java-midlet)

How do I sign a Java midlet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383771/how-do-you-sign-a-java-midlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried ? This is a [tutorial](http://www.spindriftpages.net/blog/dave/2006/06/18/midlet-jar-signing-a-tutorial-revised/) readily available on Google (which lists a set of common problems along with the signing process). If this isn't working then it's worth publishing more specific info on what isn't working.